# How to analyse sentiment of a news article using AlchemyAPI?

Tags: sentiment-analysis, alchemyapi

I want to analyse sentiment of a news article (input: text not URL) using AlchemyAPI. Please suggest me how Can I do that.

I tried with demo `http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/demo/alchemylanguage/` but it provides sentiment for each entities separately, not for the whole article text.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What language? You need to give us *much* more information.

Comment: @KenD I'm new to it. I have tried only demo given of their website. http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/demo/alchemylanguage/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the sentiment for the whole document in the demo, (see screenshot):

[image]

If you want to do it programatically, the API call you are looking for is [TextGetTextSentiment](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/sentiment/textc.html). You should first register for a free API key. Then to get the sentiment of the text "my great text", go to the following URL:

```
http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/text/TextGetTextSentiment?apikey=<YOUR_API_KEY>&sentiment=1&showSourceText=1&text=my%20great%20text
```

As you see the text is url encoded at the end. For more details take a look at the documentation of [TextGetTextSentiment](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/sentiment/textc.html).